# Accessing global variables in PHP function

Tags: php

I'm new to php and I can't understand why is it that the variable "cons" isn't recognized by the the compiler when used inside the function "func", in the following code:

```
$cons = 1;

function plusCons($num) {
   return $num + $cons;
}
```

is it impossible to use global variables inside of a function's scope?

Comment: declare it `global  $cons;` inside function. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: `function plusCons($num) use($cons) { ...`

Comment: You can, but it generally should be avoided. You should just pass the variable in as a parameter and then update it when the function returns, or use a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access global variables within a PHP function, you need to use the `global` keyword to import the variable:

```
$cons = 1;

function plusCons($num) {
   global $cons;

   return $num + $cons;
}
```

Comment: this will not work in a lot of contexts, e.g. assiging a closure to a variable inside a class method. Use `use(...)`.

Comment: Right.  Fortunately that isn't what the OP was inquiring about.

Answer (score 0):

This also will work for you:

```
$cons = 1;

function plusCons($num ,$cons) {
  return $num + $cons;
}

echo plusCons(2 , $cons); // this will output 3
```